# Change content of input depending on selected option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am facing a little problem. Here is my code (a simple form) :

```
<form id="form-mission" method="post" action="mission.php">
    <ul>
    <li class="except">
    <select name="membre">
        <option value=0> Lucy </option>
        <option value=1> John </option>
        <option value=3> Peter </option></select>
    </li>

    <!--Content-->
    <li><textarea name="texte" id="text_area" ></textarea></li>

    <!-- Submit -->
    <li class="except"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
    </ul>

</form>
```

I would like to set the textarea text depending on which name is selected but before we submit the form. In fact, when the option is changed, i want the content of the textarea also changed.

Could you help me please ?
Thanks !

Comment: What text you want to set text inside the dropdown or value of selected element in dropdown

Comment: What should happen if the user enters other text in the `textarea`? Should *just* the name be changed, or the whole content overwritten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your jquery

```
$('select[name="membre"]').on('change',function(){
    alert($('select option:selected').text());
    var get=$('select option:selected').text();
    $('#text_area').val(get);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/MgLd4/1/)

or you can add id to your dropdown and fire event on the basis of id
so your dropdown would be like this

```
<select name="membre" id="ddlMember">
        <option value=0> Lucy </option>
        <option value=1> John </option>
        <option value=3> Peter </option></select>
```

and your jquery would be

```
$('#ddlMember').on('change',function(){
    var get=$('select option:selected').text();
    document.getElementById('text_area').value=get;
});
```

Comment: I'd like to make a suggestion to add an ID to the select and use that as your selector instead. jQuery attribute selection is based off of `Sizzle` so it's a library calling a library really and the `ID` is faster than the rest. Also you can change line 4 to `document.getElementById('text_area').value=get;` no need to use jQuery for everything.

Comment: @EasyBB: thanks for your suggestion. i will add as you suggested to this solution.

Comment: i didn't added id as op didn't have id attribute. and here so many people ready to downvote if i modify op question, that's why i didn't modify the question.

Comment: No I know the OP didn't add it, just merely a suggestion to maybe add to your post for future search logs. Plus 1 for seeing my point. It was making me itch, everyone likes to use jQuery for everything :D

Comment: I would suggest adding the name to the select option in the jquery as well. If there are any other selects on the page the script will pull their values if you don't. `var get=$('select[name="membre"] option:selected').text();`

Answer (score 3):

You can use below js code

```
$('.test').change(function(){

$('#text_area').val($(".test option:selected").text());

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xAw8V/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[name="membre"]').on('change', function(){
    $('[name="texte"]').val($(this).find(":selected").text());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[name="membre"]').change(function(){
      var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
      $('#text_area').html(text );
  });
});
```

Comment: your reference on line 4 is not needed to be `.html` it should plainly be `.val` or `.value` however you run it. Yes it works but really come on.

Comment: @EasyBB, this is because for formatted text it works well than using val... thats why I have used html.